# How to know the length of a GroupingCollection in an AdvancedDatagrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, mxml

I have an `AdvancedDatagrid` populated by an `ArrayCollection` which using `GroupingCollection2` for data display.

**My issue is** : **I want to know the length of my GroupingCollection2 !**

**AND NOT** the length of the source of my grouping *(know length of an ArrayCollection is easy)* !

I did not find a way to know the length of grouped data..
And I would find a way to know the length of nodes even if they are collapsed.

For instance if I have 2 nodes with 4 childrens : length = 8 (childrens number).

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: How about the easy way.. just make a variable that updates +1 for every node and +1 for every children, then you can use that to keep track of total amounts?

Comment: I tried this way. It not works..

Comment: How come? I mean how does your code know in the first place to have 2 node and 4 children? Where it knows that info the custom length variable can also be updated. Example if its a `For Loop` you're using and have also `public var num_Node_Children:int = 0;` then each loop to add a node-child will also do `num_Node_Children += 1;` later trace `num_Node_Children` to get total..

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I think it's impossible to loop on a `GroupingCollection2` and count `num_Node_Children` directly. Nodes are made by the Grouping, it's not me with a loop..

Comment: Ahh I understand you now. I'm more Flash than Flex so we dont get these goodies like Advanced Datagrids. I'm used to manually organised data. Anyways can these info not be extracted from the `source` that feeds `GroupingCollection2` with info. Basically "predict" how much of required data will end up in the grouping collection. You predict by processing the source-data before grouping (would XML-style parsing work here?)..

Comment: Yes before grouping it's possible. **BUT** in fact I use filter on my `GroupingCollection2`, so I need to know the length after grouping.. I tried to "ungroup" to count the length and group again after, it not works..